# How much wiggle room should I give when creating a package design?

Tags: packaging

I'm designing box art for a card game but I've never really designed packages before. The layout, I think, is really simple to create, but I don't know how much room to give to let the cards slide in ant out relatively easily and to have the game instructions not too tight.

the dimensions of the cards are business card size (3.5" x 2") and stacked two piles high to make the box a little thinner. So I have the front measuring 3.5"x4". I measured out the height of the two stacks to be about .78".

Is there some standard or suggested measurements when making this type of packaging and how much room to give?

[image]

Comment: I have no idea,  but here's what I'd do: buy a pack of similar cards (playing cards, Pokemon Cards, Magic cards, whatever) and get measurements from that. Note both the box inner diameter and outer diameter, then carefully "unglue" the box so that it can lay flat like your template so you can take precise measurements. That would establish a baseline, and I'd figure out my dimensions from there.

Comment: Just like figuring a spine for a perfect bound book.... it all depends upon the thickness of the stock the cards are printed on.

Comment: @scott I already measured the stock I'm printing the cards on. It's the .78" I mentioned above.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a packaging designer, I tend to leave around 1 to 2mm around the product depending on the thickness of the material, always do prototypes and test before final production.